# CSS Navigation Menus - Dynamic widths

Tags: css, navigation

I've been using the SuckerFish menus for pretty much ever right now...  however I need something a little newer.  mainly something that will handle drop-down items and fly-outs of variable widths. i.e. I may have 6 drop-down main items, each sub-menu needs to be a variable [dynamic] width AND the fly-outs for each are also of differing widths.
SuckerFish does not handle variable widths for the drop-downs particularly well ....  has anyone got any suggestions?

The site is using jQuery, though I am not too hot on javascript 'anything' for navigation a pure CSS would be nice if possible.

-thanks
-sean

Comment: Suckerfish does not handle drop-down items well? Or the variable width? @alex thinks you're talking about animation, can you clarify this question and title?

Comment: No it's the widths, I'm not interested in animating them at all....

Answer (score 0):

CSS has limited [animations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_Animations) with limited [browser support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_Animations#Browser_support) (looks like only the latest WebKits).

For a cross browser animated menu, you'll have to leverage JavaScript.

jQuery will make doing it quicker and less painful, but is not a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You could set things up with your usual SuckerFish as a baseline and then add [Superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/) on top of that to provide the fancy animations and what not. Superfish is built with jQuery so it should drop in fairly easily.